# Better way to pass parameters to ruby calabash method

Tags: ruby, if-statement, case, calabash

I have the following ruby calabash step:

```
When(/^I enter (phone number|email)$/) do |method|
login_type = case method
        when 'phone number'
          true
        when 'email'
          false
        else
          raise("#{method} is not supported")
      end
verify_login_page(type: login_type)
aggregator = case method
             when 'phone number'
               Aggregator::PHONE
             when 'email'
               Aggregator::EMAIL
             else
               Aggregator::ALL
           end
get_and_enter_code(aggregator)
end
```

Even though it seems clear, I'm pretty sure I can make it better from design perspective. Especially what I don't like is login_type case method with true/false assignment.
How it's better to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator assignment:

```
When(/^I enter (phone number|email)$/) do |method|
  unless  ['phone number', 'email'].include?(method)
    raise "#{method} is not supported"
  else
    login_type = method == 'phone number' ? true : false
  end

  verify_login_page(type: login_type)

  aggregator = login_type ? Aggregator::PHONE : Aggregator::EMAIL

  get_and_enter_code(aggregator)
end
```

Since you raise exception `Aggregator::ALL` case should never occur.

Comment: thanks! to be honest Aggregator::ALL  is an artefact after I removed the other code to put an example here, sorry for confusion